# How to set the value of a variable of derived class by using the base class object?

Tags: c++

I need to assign `x = 2000` to `x` of `B` via object `a` of `A`

Here B is the derived class i.e inherits the class A.

```
 class A
{
public:
    int x, y;
    void print()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"print() of A";
    }
    virtual void display()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"display() of A";
    }
};
class B: public A
{
public:
    int x, z;
    void display()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"display() of B";
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"print() of B";
    }
};
```

Comment: You seem to have *some* understanding of virtual functions. Continue experimenting with them, perhaps creating a virtual `set_x` function?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer by doing the following:

```
((B *)aptr)->x = 2000;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, polymorphism is implemented via virtual functions. If you need to change something in a derived class through a pointer or reference to its base type, you need a virtual function. (Well, technically, you don't; you could cast to the derived type, but that's an admission of design failure).

Comment: here my display() is virtual. But I have to assign x = 2000 to the child class's variable through the base class object.

Comment: It could be done by ((B *)aptr)->x = 2000; which is pointer to object, but I need to do it by Object of A only not pointer to object. @Pete Becker

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by creating virtual function in base class which effect to call function of derive class for initialization.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

 class A
{
public:
    int x, y;
    void print()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"print() of A";
    }
    virtual void display()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"display() of A";
    }

    virtual void setX(int a)
    {

    }
};
class B: public A
{
public:
    int x, z;
    void display()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"display() of B";
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"print() of B";
    }

    void setX(int a)
    {
        x=a;
    }
};


int main()
{
    A *ptr;
    B b;
    ptr=&b;
    ptr->setX(2000); ///using pointer object of class A 
    cout<<b.x;


}
```

I think it will help you :)